# got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields', User needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-models

My models.py:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Headline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(default="")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='like', blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='dislike', blank=True)
    lols = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='lol', blank=True)
    saves = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='save', blank=True)
    bearishes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='bearish', blank=True)
    importants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='important', blank=True)
    toxics = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='toxic', blank=True)

    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    newspost = models.ForeignKey(Headline, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author}"
```

When I add a few ManyToMany field related to User model, it causes error when login/register/etc. These errors:

> File
> "/Users/mahdi/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py",
> line 1584, in _changeform_view
> self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
>
> File
> "/Users/mahdi/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py",
> line 1097, in save_model
> obj.save()
>
> File
> "/Users/mahdi/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
> line 536, in **get**
> return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
>
> File
> "/Users/mahdi/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py",
> line 853, in **init**
> (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
>
> ValueError: "<User: test>" needs to have a value for field "id" before
> this many-to-many relationship can be used.

What's wrong?

Comment: Share the view behind `login/register/`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't have any view for that. Just using the built-in admin page of django currently.